# Logo Image Centered & Menu Bar Below Logo

Tags: html, css

The logo of a site I am working appears on  the left but i want it to be centered. How can I go about it ? Find below the CSS code.

```css
header .logo{ display: inline-block; padding: 0; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Also the menu bar appear on the right hand side of the logo but I want it to be centered and below the logo. How can I do that?

```css
.nav-right-area{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.navigation{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.navigation > ul{ margin-top: 0px;}
.navbar{ margin-bottom: 0; min-height: inherit;}
```

Image if the header of the site where the logo and the menu shows is found below:[image]

Link to the site is http://midwaycinema7.com/

Heads up will be appreciated.

Comment: please add the html part

Comment: Do you want your logo vertically centered?

Comment: I want the logo to be horizontally centered

Comment: try using flex-box concept. It will be responsive for all devices without a lot of code.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot,  Kindly expatiate on your suggestion and if possible add code

Comment: There are a few ways to horizontally center it. 1. You may use <center> tag around your logo. 2. You may use margin:auto of css. 3. You may set its positions dynamically using jquery. 4.You can use flex-box system to get it into center.

Comment: this my help you. : https://jsfiddle.net/bqwt3vqy/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do it.

1. Using **Flex**.

   ```
   .divHoldingYourLogo{
     display:flex;
     justify-content: center; 
   }
   ```
2. Using **Center Tag**.

   ```
   <div> 
      <center>
         <img src="logo.jpg" class="YOUR CLASSES">
      </center>
   </div>
   ```

   *But its not used now*.

   3.Using **`margin:auto`**

   ```
   .divHoldingYourLogo{
       display:block;
    }

   #logo{
    margin:auto;
   }
   ```

   4. Using **Jquery**

You can also do it by getting the $(window).width() and divide it by 2 and set that to be the `margin-left` or in case of `position:absolute` the `property` `left` with that value.

So there are many solutions to this. You may choose the approach that suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Better provide full html layout. or below code is something you can do to get logo and menu horizontally centered:

For Logo:

```
header .logo{ display: block; width: 50%; margin: auto auto; padding: 0;}
```

navigation menu should be wrapped inside outer element with bellow css:

```
.navigation-wrap{ display: block; min-width: 50%; margin: auto auto; }
```

---

this is just idea, try to adjust it according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to center and raise your div above the menu on the http://midwaycinema7.com/about/ link you originally provided, here's my solution:

Go to your CSS, find the

```
.main-head .col-lg-2 {

}
```

rule and change `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;`. Also, add a `width: initial;`. Your html elements and your CSS have gotten kind of convoluted and using `width: initial` was one way I found to reset this width so that your logo is dead-center.